# How to get Anchor Javascript to Submit in IE. Working in FF, Chrome and Safari.

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Good Morning Stackoverflow-ka-teers,

I am creating a raffle form that allows you to enter in your name and then select your location from a dropdown list.  Once you have done both, you click the submit, and the form posts into a database

Simple enough.

Works fantastic in Chrome, Firefox, and even Safari (has to due to the client wants this to work on an iPad).... but when it comes to IE8, all hell breaks loose!

I noticed on my SUBMIT button this little funky thing that is ONLY appearing in IE8

```
<a id="submit" onclick="javascript:submit()" href="javascript:void(null)" jQuery171013871964676587128="2">
```

**What the HELL is that jQuery string that equals 2?**

My other concern is when I null out BOTH the href and the onclick attributes on the SUBMIT button, the submit function still executes, but only in IE8.

**

> Why is there saying paper jam, when there IS no paper jam?

**

Comment: 1) never call anything submit. 2) `onclick="submitForm(); return false"` will work better (not unobtrusive) where submitform is the `function submitForm()` that calls your form submission. That is for plain JS. Now ask a NEW question without the profanity and irrelevant comments and show the jQuery you have along with the form html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a way to "brute-force" it, you might try to force IE to render as IE7.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Also, is there a reason why you're mixing the HTML onclick with jQuery, instead of just using jQuery to attach the event?

Comment: Yeah.  That way you can keep your 'interaction' separate from your 'structure', just like you separate the 'presentation' (CSS) from your 'structure' (HTML).  It makes it easier to maintain over time.

Comment: would you believe that simply removing the onClicks and adding a .click function solved the entire problem I was having.  Thank you Tim Bolton (hopefully no relation to Michael)

Comment: @Murphy1976 That's my father.  Seriously. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the `jQuery187346918723649817623498` attribute, it is just used for jQuery and can be found in the other browsers too if you look hard enough. Your problem must be elsewhere, more than likely a miss-placed comma or invalid html/js.